# Extracting Points from Lines using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to extract points from a line on an image using openCV in C++ Language.  The line is programmed to display on the image, but I need to know how do you extract points from line and input it into a text file?

Comment: Do you want to detect the line, or do you know where the line is?

Comment: You really should clarify your question.  What is the input? Image that has lines in it?  What do you mean by "the line is programmed to display on the image"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get each point of the raster line using [`cv::LineIterator`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator) class, e.g.:

```
// grabs pixels along the line (pt1, pt2)
// from 8-bit 3-channel image to the buffer
LineIterator it(img, pt1, pt2, 8);
LineIterator it2 = it;
vector<Vec3b> buf(it.count);

for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
    buf[i] = *(const Vec3b)*it;

// alternative way of iterating through the line
for(int i = 0; i < it2.count; i++, ++it2)
{
    Vec3b val = img.at<Vec3b>(it2.pos());
    CV_Assert(buf[i] == val);
}
```